# How to Visualize Time series graph's X axis from relative zero instead of real time point using Grafana

Tags: grafana

I am trying to generate grafana time series graph. Below is an example-

[image]

The time points on x axis shows real time when the data was taken. I want to start the time points from 0 and show relative time points like 0, 5min, 10min etc. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Grafana does not support this functionality, and probably won't any time soon. You should look for some other platform/solution if this feature is critical for your use.